# Cpu usage of String[] s = str.split(",")

Tags: java

Here is my code :

```
String[] s = str.split(",")
```

But,by the `jstack` file,i find the usage of the code is very high.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2353)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
```

Why the code need `Arrays.copyOfRange`?I should definition `String[length]` first?

Comment: have you looked at the code? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29

Comment: *"i find the usage of the code is very high."* compared to what? Is that really the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: If you are working on an IDE like Eclipse or Netbean you can jump into String class to see why `split` method call the `Arrays.copyOfRange`.
It's just normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the code need `Arrays.copyOfRange`?

Because `split` creates new `String`s thanks to `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` which internally calls `new String(char value[], int offset, int count)`, and as a `String` is **immutable**, it does a safe copy of the provided `char` `array` to avoid been affected by any external modifications because otherwise your `String` instance would then be potentially mutable which is what we want to avoid.

Check the javadoc of [`String(char value[], int offset, int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-int-int-):

> Allocates a new `String` that contains characters from a subarray of the
>   character array argument. The offset argument is the index of the
>   first character of the subarray and the count argument specifies the
>   length of the subarray. **The contents of the subarray are copied;
>   subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the
>   newly created string.**